# Word for: Sleep until some bad situation/feeling subsides or ends

Tags: phrasal-verbs, phrase-requests

When one waits until some difficulty has passed, we say "wait something out". Is there a word/expression in English for sleeping until your hunger, pain, or negative emotions subside?

Comment: Does "hibernate" work?

Comment: @Cascabel - When you have just broken up with your partner, and go to bed feeling like you want to sleep and never wake up, do you "hibernate"? :-D

Comment: Maybe you need to provide more context, along with some research indicating words that you considered and then rejected...

Comment: I think "sleep off" is sometimes used in this context.  "He slept off his worries."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is

> Sleep it off

meaning to

> to stop the bad effects of having too much of something by sleeping for as long as it takes to end those effects

[Link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sleep-it-off)

For hunger specifically there’s a very modern phrase I’ve heard

> Having sleep for dinner

But it’s so new that I can’t really find many references for it other than Urban Dictionary and Reddit/Twitter usage.

Comment: I want to accept the second answer, sleep off. Would you consider editing your answer? Because the first one is specific to one situation.

Comment: @Adam certainly

Comment: "Sleep for dinner" - Never heard this phrase in 70+ years in Britain. It sounds like a translation from some other language.

Comment: @Anton it’s exceedingly modern. I’ve only heard it in the past year or two.